# Why two external dryer vents?

Tags: dryer

In the back of my house I see two external dryer vents. I am sure one isn't for the dryer.

I live in a townhouse and all the townhouses have these two vents so its not a reroute job.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vents could be

- **exhaust** for dryers, bathroom exhaust fans, stovetop exhaust hoods;
- **intake** (fresh air supply) for gas- or oil-burning appliances (furnaces, water heaters, fireplaces);
- or **plumbing vents**. (Although plumbing vents would typically be through the roof.)

Can you follow the duct inside to see where it goes?

Comment: One thing that can be done is to turn on various items, such as @HenryJackson has enumerated, one by one and see of you can detect sound, air flow or warmth out of the vent exit at the external location.

Comment: It is most likely a bathroom or laundry closet vent.

Comment: could also be intake/exhaust for a [heat recovery ventilator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_recovery_ventilation) (though much less common)